# Show that a piecewise function of two solutions to an ODE is a solution to the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, alternative-proof

Let $x=x(t)$. If the first order ODE $x'=f(t,x) (*)$ is satisfied by $u$ and $v$, each over $I = (a,b)$, show that

$$w(t) := u1_{(a,t_0)} + v1_{[t_0,b)}$$

satisfies $(*)$, where

$u(t_0) = v(t_0)$ for some $t_0 \in (a,b)$.

So, we must show that $w'=f(t,w)$.

Not sure if it matters, but we can deduce that $u'(t_0) = v'(t_0)$.

---

What I tried:

$$LHS = w'(t) = u'(t) 1_{(a,t_0)} + v'(t) 1_{[t_0,b)}$$

$$RHS = f(t,w) = f(t, u(t) 1_{(a,t_0)} + v(t) 1_{[t_0,b)})$$

Is it okay to take cases? Is there another way to do it besides taking cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $u'(t)=f(t,u(t))$ and $v'(t)=f(t,v(t))$.

Hence, for $t<t_0$ we have
$$w'(t)=u'(t)=f(t,u(t))=f(t,w(t)),$$
while for $t>t_0$,
$$w'(t)=v'(t)=f(t,v(t))=f(t,w(t)).$$
Moreover, since $u(t_0)=v(t_0)$, the function $w$ is continuous and $w$ is a (weak) solution of the differential equation.

**Added:**

To be a *weak* solution means that $w(t)=c+\int_{t_0}^t f(s,w(s))\,ds$ for all $t$ in some open neighborhood of $t_0$, where $c=u(t_0)=v(t_0)$. This means that in general we look for solutions that are at most continuous at $t_0$. In other words, and without further hypothesis, one cannot expect that $w$ is differentiable at $t_0$.

But, for example, if $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $x$, then the solutions are unique and of course $w$ will be differentiable at $t_0$ with $w'(t_0)=u'(t_0)=v'(t_0)$. However, in that case, the problem is not very interesting since than we have in fact $u(t)=v(t)$ in in some open neighborhood of $t_0$ (and so also $w(t)=u(t)=v(t)$ in in some open neighborhood of $t_0$).

Comment: So what's the answer to my first question? Second?

Comment: Indeed, it is what I did ("take cases"). No, there is no other way.

Comment: I just remember from advanced probability class there was this weird thing where someone's answer to a past LT was taking cases and it wasn't allowed so now I am paranoid. Are there conditions on the f that allow us to do something else? Maybe linearity in x or something?

Comment: No, you want too much. Without strong hypotheses (and you have no hypotheses) you can't do anything else.

Comment: I think there might be some hypotheses stated earlier in the text which I overlooked or thought not to be important. What hypotheses did you have in mind? Btw is the fact that u and v are tangent at $t_0$ relevant?

Comment: I already replied to what you asked. Now you ask something completely different and in mathematics one cannot work without hypotheses. Since they can be of so many types, it is impossible to be detailed without using an unreasonable amount of time.

Comment: I was thinking that you had some in mind. Well thanks for answering. And thanks anyway. How about the tangency fact?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the tangency. I will now add details to my answer about that point.

Comment: I'll assume the answer is no. Thanks Jonas :P

Comment: Yes, better as you say. :-)